# What is the effective radius of stellar graviton emission?

Tags: gravitational-waves, gravitational-redshift, white-dwarfs

White dwarfs have been used to accurately determine photon gravitational redshift:https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?as_ylo=2016&q=white+dwarf+gravitational+redshift&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5#d=gs_qabs&u=%23p%3DOE1jghxBr2MJ

Their small radius, at which photons are emitted, gives a redshift O(80kms-1), which can be measured very accurately.

But at what radius are gravitons emitted, and consequently what is their redshift ?

**Edit**
Comments indicate that stellar mass emit gravitons uniformly, as expected.
However, this implies significant redshift and yet no commenting or answering re the implications of this.

Comment: Gravitons are completely theoretical. No one has ever detected one (although we have detected gravitational waves ), and no one will in the foreseeable future.

Comment: However, I would expect gravitons to be generate throughout the interior of a white dwarf. Unlike photons, they can easily get out.

Comment: Intriguing. There's no evidence they exist, but we know how they behave.

Comment: Yes, there is a standard theory of gravitons, from linearizing and quantizing Einstein’s field equations. It doesn’t make sense at high energies but at low energies it explains Newtonian gravity very nicely in terms of gravitons.

Comment: Note that most stars are fairly symmetric around their rotation axis, and therefore will emit any gravitational radiation by themselves (or gravitons for that matter).

Comment: @mmeent I think you accidentally said the opposite of what you meant...

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, there should be a not in that sentence.